# Is there an easy way to check if the substring is in quotes or no?

Tags: php, string, domdocument

I struggling to work with a string containing an HTML web-page. My particular one has some quoted HTML tags within `<script>` container. Just like this:

```
<script>
  a = '<div>';
  b = '</script>';
</script>
```

Let's say I'd like to delete all `<script>` containers from this string but I need not to treat `'</script>'` substring as the closing `<script>` tag.

So is there any easy way to pass through this thing?

I know that I can use DOMDocument to manipulate with this string, but I'd like to do it manually as I'm debugging the script using DOMDocument manipulations and it's working in unexpected way.

Comment: Is it intentional that `b=</script>';` has no opening quote?

Comment: You're right, @Nikos. My mistype.

Answer (score 1):

you could loop through your string and do a strpos of  in your string. Then do +1 or -1 to see if the script has a ' to the left or right of it. - Another more complex way.

Comment: I'd say this is the `not an easy` approach. So there is no any function or anything? For example something like this: `if(InQuotes($str,strpos($str,'<div>')))`

Answer (score 0):

Use strip_tags function:

http://php.net/strip_tags

It allows you to select which tags to strip and which to leave.

Comment: While this is correct, I would suggest providing a code sample to improve your answer.

Comment: This answer is correct in general, but I'd like to get the solution for the particular answered question (about the quotes).